# Sharepoint online sites are showing up in different language than the default language

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am facing an issue where one user is seeing the site in a different language than english( default language). i have checked user profile language settings and client machine settings. Both are setup for english. I have checked with user on a different machine and the same issue persists. This is happening in few sites only. Multilingual settings are not enabled on sites. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Here are steps:

1. Select your name or picture at the top of any SharePoint or Microsoft 365 site in your organization.
2. Select My Microsoft 365 profile

   [image]
3. Setting->Change your language

   [image]